Why is the Quarto kickstarter for Neovim not autocompleting citations?
Long-time vim user, but new to Neovim and lua config stuff.
My setup is Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2, using quarto 1.5.56 and /usr/bin/pandoc 3.4. I cloned the (excellent!) Quarto kickstarter and made no other alterations. QuartoPreview works properly, including resolving citations, but the cmp-pandoc-references plugin is not completing citations while I edit. Here is a sample Quarto file:
---
title: My Test Document
bibliography: ./test.bib
format: html
---

# Heading 1

A reference [@test1].

# Bibliography

And here is the bib file
@article{test1,
  title = {Test Document 1},
  author = {Author, Jane},
  year = {2023},
  journal = {my journal},
}

On typing [@t I get completion options from other sources, but not from the bib file.

What should I try next to debug this problem? I'm new to the whole Neovim / LazyVim setup and I've tried removing various bits from the configuration, but in a very hit-and-miss fashion, with no luck so far.
